# Interpreting Odds Ratio (in an Interaction)

Tags: regression, logistic, odds

I need advice on the correct interpretation of an odds ratio of an interaction term.

Both the mixed-effect logistic regression output is below as well as the predicted odds values, which I calculate merely to help me visualize what the OR values in the output are referring to.

The dependent variable is whether a household owned a television. We are interested in the effects of household head gender (Female, Male), wealth status (Poor, Middle, Rich), and the interaction between these variables. This is hypothetical given the confidentiality of the dataset I'm working with. I've also excluded other predictors here to shorten the length of the post.

The base levels are set to Male and Rich. As we can see in the predicted odds values table below, the odds of Female#Rich owning a TV is 7.2; the odds of Male#Rich is 2.0. This is represented in the regression output under Female (OR: 3.58). Given gender is one component of the interaction term, it no longer represents the unique effects of head-gender, and is interpreted in relation to the base level for wealth (i.e., Rich). We can do the same for Female#Poor (OV: 3.99) and Male#Poor (OV: 4.2) [OR: 0.95, omitted from the regression ouput] and Female#Middle (OV: 2.8) and Male#Middle (OV: 2.6) [OR: 1.048, ommitted]. In both cases, the OR is much closer to 1 than at the rich level (3.58).

The regression output lists the OR in the interaction for Female#Poor and Female#Medium as 0.27 and 0.29, respectively.

Conceptually, it indicates the difference in the odds between female and males in owning a TV is much smaller at poor and middle wealth levels, compared to a rich level (where we know the gendered difference is much larger). **I'm looking for help on how to interpret this in numerical terms.** I had originally thought of writing the difference in the odds of owning a TV between male and female heads is 70% smaller at middle-class level, as compared to a rich level -- however, I don't think that intuition is right.

```
                    TV_owner   | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                  hhead_gender |
                       Female  |   3.577116   1.585295     2.88   0.004     1.500722      8.5264
                               |
             Status_Ladder_Cat |
                        Poor   |   2.092556   .5473432     2.82   0.005      1.25323    3.494002
                       Middle  |   1.309231   .3067593     1.15   0.250     .8271336    2.072321
                               |
hhead_gender#Status_Ladder_Cat |
                   Female#Poor |   .2661135   .1304397    -2.70   0.007      .101821    .6954992
                Female#Middle  |   .2930256   .1347962    -2.67   0.008     .1189433    .7218902
```

Here are the predicted odds values:

```
                               |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                  hhead_gender |
                       Female  |    3.57335    1.00732     3.55   0.000     1.599038    5.547662
                         Male  |   3.040049   .8109692     3.75   0.000     1.450579     4.62952
                               |
             Status_Ladder_Cat |
                         Rich  |   3.936832   1.453617     2.71   0.007     1.087794     6.78587
                          Poor |   4.122344   1.165546     3.54   0.000     1.837915    6.406773
                       Middle  |   2.673619   .6924266     3.86   0.000     1.316488     4.03075
                               |
hhead_gender#Status_Ladder_Cat |
                  Female#Rich  |   7.175792   3.313105     2.17   0.030     .6822246    13.66936
                   Female#Poor |   3.995892   1.269603     3.15   0.002     1.507515    6.484269
                Female#Middle  |   2.752908   .7712539     3.57   0.000     1.241278    4.264538
                    Male#Rich  |   2.006027   .6562206     3.06   0.002     .7198586    3.292196
                     Male#Poor |   4.197724   1.252428     3.35   0.001     1.743011    6.652437
                  Male#Middle  |   2.626354   .7001336     3.75   0.000     1.254117     3.99859
```

Comment: On the face of it, households headed by a rich male owning a TV having odds of $2$ owning a TV corresponds to the proportion of such families having a TV being only about $67\%$, which seems low to me.  You can do the same with the others, finding the predicted proportion being $\frac{\text{odds}}{\text{odds }+1}$

Comment: Thanks. It seems low because the data is fictional for this specific example. I modified for confidentiality. My odds value to predicted probability is considerably lower than 67%, but that is likely because I'm using multiple additional predictors (ommitted in this example), the software (Stata) is calculating the predictions using the observed values of these variables as well?